# Targeting header title in uitableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `uitableview` populated by core data. I am populating the table with the results I require, however I wish the header title of each cell to contain the date. Is there a easy way to do this and how would I proceed? Currently I am populating a label using a tag but I wish to show it in the header section of each cell. Thanks for any help.

```
//Convert NSDate to String and show in Tag 12
    NSDate *weightDate = [measure valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *result = [df stringFromDate:weightDate];
    UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    [label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result]];
```

Comment: are you using sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use one row per/section

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}
```

and give number of sections as number of rows

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
return datasourceArray.count   // i am imagining datasource array has the row details for your table view..
}
```

then instead of using `indexPath.row` use `indexPath.section`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//cell intialization deque codes here

cell.titleLabel.text=[datasourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"title"];
return cell;
}
```

then,You can always give header for section ..

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   NSDate *weightDate = [measure valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *result = [df stringFromDate:weightDate];
return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi raon. Looks good thanks. Only issue I'm having is when I put    NSManagedObject *measure = [self.measurements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDate *weightDate = [measure valueForKey:@"date"];
   NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *result = [df stringFromDate:weightDate];
    
    return result; into the titleforheaderinsection it comes up with a error for indexpath. Whats the best way to sort this?

Comment: @AlbaClan you should never use NSManaged objects directly in the code... You should only  consider updates and insertion on NSManaged objects.. coz using them directly may lead to inconsistancy.. Y ou should use Model classes for corresponding NSManaged objects to do operations on it.

Comment: you should use

[self.measurements objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; instead of [self.measurements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: hi there @raon. I still get an error in regards to indexpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return @"String";
}
```